# Add to current CSS top value

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery:

```
$(".ta").siblings(".Aname:eq(0)").css("top",+=$(".Text").height()+15);
```

But it is not working. I have tried this way too:

```
$(".ta").siblings(".Aname:eq(0)").css("top",'+=$(".Text").height()+15');
```

But it also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to grab the current top value, and then add a new value, and then append the "px" back on when you set the value using .css()

Here is what it would look like:

```
var element = $(".ta").siblings(".Aname:eq(0)");
var currTop = Number(element.css("top").replace("px", ""));
var amountToAdd = $(".Text").height() + 15;
$(element).css("top", (currTop + amountToAdd + "px"));
```

**[And here is a WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qisocefulu/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Bless you for sharing your knowledge with us!

Comment: Perhaps you could explain me what "Number" is on 2 line?

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to upvote and mark the answer as accepted so that future visitors can quickly identify a working solution.

Comment: indeed after 1 minute.It will not let me do this rn

Comment: @JonSnow'spapa So, element.css("top") will return, say "2px". We are really only interested in the 2 for calculation purposes. We can strip the "px" off by using .replace("px", ""), however, we are left with "2". And if we add "2" + 2, we get "22", not 4. That's where Number() comes in. Number() is an explicit cast of a string to a number. That way we can do 2 + 2 = 4. Which is why we have to add in the "px" again at the end when we set the .css() value, otherwise it will be an invalid css property value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Here are the docs for Number() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: Thanks for your help again